# Automated Event with Php

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php code to check if a date is passed so i can display or not or do something.

I want to modify it and make an Automated Post system like FB's! So below is my php code that i already found and working as it is.

```
$regdate = "20/10/2009"; // recording date
$d = explode("/",$regdate); //date in array
$day = $d[0]+10; // Plus ten days
$end_timestamp = mktime("0","0","0",$d[1],$day,$d[2]); //Expiration date Timestamp
$thismoment = time(); // Current Timestamp
if ($end_timestamp > $thismoment) // Compare
{ 
echo "Hello Word";
}
```

How can i modify it so in a specific date and time my script send an email?

For example i want at 22/04/2013 at 14:30 my script i want to do something? (Like facebook's Aumated post)

Regards

Comment: use cron job for automated event

Comment: impossible with pure php. you need a cronjob, or a cgi script. Maybe a node.js server and Server Send Events.

Comment: you *could* but shouldn't loop your script. e.g. the script calls itself with CURL or fsocket every 10 seconds or so. but this is not recommened

Comment: btw. FB uses either polling or push. If this should only happen when a user is on your site try polling with JavaScript.

Comment: @mercsen i will use cron job to visit specific file so like someone visit my web page very 1 minute!! So if i can do it how can modify my script?

Comment: `= $d[0]+10;` what if the date is 31? then it will be 41

Comment: what exactly do you want? You want an automated change at the client? Also impossible with pure PHP. PHO is only executed on the server side, for a automated post update you need javascript. PHP could only update the database or something on the server side. It could also invoke a push to the client using a proxy server but not change the alredy recived output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 choices (at least):

- Use cron jobs offered by system (Linux/Unix)
- Run your PHP script in console as a daemon, see my example code below.

> ```
> <?php
> define("MY_DEFINED_TIME", strtotime("22/04/2013 14:30"));
> while (true) {
>     if (time()==MY_DEFINED_TIME) {
>         //send your email
>         echo "Hello world";
>         break;
>     }
>     sleep (1); // have a rest
> }
> ```

You can run your daemon with this command :

> nohup php your_script.php 2>&1 >> /tmp/your_script.log &

Then you can find the output in /tmp/your_script.log when any error appeared.
Hope this helpful.

Comment: whats with MAX_EXECUTION_TIME?

Comment: The maximum execution time is set to unlimited, when you run PHP from console. see http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.differences.php

Comment: ok, i didn't know it, thats why i asked ;) But i think that is not what php was designed for. I would prefer ruby or even perl

Comment: @mercsen Yes, PHP is not designed for daemon. But my company used PHP scripts as daemon in production environment during last years, and it works fine. Just FYI :-P

Comment: Im always interesed in such things! ;) I didn't want to judge someone. I apologize if i gave you this feeling